# Apache LocationMatch

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to add an Apache directive to check the URL which matches with http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php or http://www.domain.com/anything/wp-login.php, but not URL like http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php?action=somthing which has something following the wp-login.php

I tried the following code, but it also match the "wp-login.php?action=somthing" string. What's the correct Reg Expression?

```
 <LocationMatch "wp-login.php$">
 ....
 </LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string being matched by `LocationMatch` doesn't include the query string.  If you need to alter your request's handling based on the query string, you'll need to use `mod_rewrite` instead.